# datagridview и DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть 2 класса:

1)

```
class Project 
{
  string ProjectName
  int OwnerId
  string OwnerName
}
```

2)

```
   Class Owner

    {
    string OwnerName
    int OwnerId
    }
```

Есть DataGridView, который состоит из 2 ух полей:

ProjectName, которое является обычным текстовым полем и OwnerName, которое является ComboBox'ом.

На DataGridView биндится List, а на ComboBox в DataGridView биндится List .

Я хочу, выбирая из ComboBox'a элемент, обновлять этими значениями элемент в

List (Присваивать OwnerId и OwnerName).

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Я смастерил вот такой костыль и на каждое изменение, я должен руками вытаскивать эти значения из DataSet, который подключен к ComboBox.

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var editedItem = (Project)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        var value = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[nameof(OwnerName)]).Value;
        var result = ((List<Owner>) Owner.DataSource).Single(x => x.OwnerName == value);
        editedItem.OwnerId = result.OwnerId;
        editedItem.OwnerName = result.OwnerName;
    }
```

Подскажите, можно ли как-нибудь менее костыльно сделать?

Comment: Может, классу Project добавить свойство типа Owner? `class Project { .... Owner Owner }`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, можно попробовать. Однако, я все равно не могу получить объект из DataGridViewComboBoxCell, а получаю только значение.

Comment: Тогда, покажите путем изменения вопроса, что вы сделали и как.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну вот этим приведением я получаю только значение, а не объект var value = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[nameof(OwnerName)]).Value;

Comment: Пожалуйста, обновите Ваш вопрос, и в нем укажите, что и как вы изменили. Не надо писать в комментариях.